# Text-align not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, sublimetext

So I'm trying to figure out why the text-align won't work in this code. I think it's a problem with Sublime Text 3. Whenever I try to Open in Browser, the alignment isn't right.

My code looks like this:

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

#red {
  color: red;
}

#blue {
  color: blue;
}

#green {
  color: green;
}

.big {
  font-size: 300%;
}

.small {
  font-size: 30%;
}

#bold {}
```

```html
<!-- Center -->
<h1 class="center">The Wonders of CSS!</h1>
<hr>
<h2>Fun With Text!</h2>
<!-- Change text color -->
<p id="red">This text is red.</p>
<p id="blue">This text is blue.</p>
<p id="green">This text is green.</p>
<!-- Change font-size -->
<p class="big">This text is BIG!</p>
<p class="small">This text is tiny...</p>
<!-- Center -->
<p class="center">~~This text is centered~~</p>
<!-- Bold -->
<p id="bold">If we have something important to say, we can make it bold!</p>
<!-- Change font -->
<p id="font">We can even change our font-family if we are feeling creative!</p>
```

Can I fix this in Sublime Text? Am I going to have to buy something? (sigh)

Comment: it's working fine

Comment: No need <style></style> tags in style.css

Comment: If you right-click the `This text is centered` in your browser and go to "Inspect Element", does it show the `text-align: center;` being applied?  If you view the page in Chrome and do a hard-refresh (`CTRL + F5`), is the issue resolved?

Comment: I tried doing the hard refresh and even restarting Chrome. Nothing is working.

Comment: Tried to add a screenshot but couldn't. Basically "The Wonders of CSS!" and "~~This text is centered~~" are both still aligned to the left.

Comment: Use https://prnt.sc to share the screenshot. How do you see "The Wonders of CSS!" and "~~This text is centered~~" here when you click "Run code snippet"? Did you try to open in some other browser beside Chrome. Try even in IE :D

Comment: Is the snippet working fine for you ? if it does, then the problem is elsewhere in your code , a typo, style overriden by another selector, ...

Comment: I think the problem is with Sublime Text! lol The snippet runs fine, but I've been using Sublime Text to write the code and whenever I click "Open in Browser," the alignment isn't working. I'm assuming I'm missing some kind of package that I'm not willing to pay for.

Comment: i added the sublime text tag to your question, you should update your question about it and which version you use ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your `.center`selector is indeed centering the elements that have the class applied to them.

Don't forget that in order for other elements to be centralised, you'll need to apply the `.center` class to them as well (for example, `<p id="red" class="center>`).

It's also possible that **[CSS caching](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/)** issues are causing your CSS changes to not reflect correctly. In order to resolve this, ensure that you have reloaded the CSS file with <kbd>CTRL + F5</kbd> and refreshed your CSS cache by holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while clicking on the refresh icon.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

#red {
  color: red;
}

#blue {
  color: blue;
}

#green {
  color: green;
}

.big {
  font-size: 300%;
}

.small {
  font-size: 30%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <!-- Center -->
  <h1 class="center">The Wonders of CSS!</h1>

  <hr>

  <h2>Fun With Text!</h2>

  <!-- Change text color -->
  <p id="red">This text is red.</p>
  <p id="blue">This text is blue.</p>
  <p id="green">This text is green.</p>

  <!-- Change font-size -->
  <p class="big">This text is BIG!</p>
  <p class="small">This text is tiny...</p>

  <!-- Center -->
  <p class="center">~~This text is centered~~</p>

  <!-- Bold -->
  <p id="bold">If we have something important to say, we can make it bold!</p>

  <!-- Change font -->
  <p id="font">We can even change our font-family if we are feeling creative!</p>

</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your class should work fine, it does center your text. However, the div might be only as big as the text. 
Try to give the `.text-center` class a `width: 100%;`